# Jquery how to replace an attribute of all p occurances inside a div?

Tags: jquery

How to replace an attribute of all p occurances inside a div?

for example I want to change font size of all "p" inside div id #div1:

```
....
<div id="div1">
 <p>text1</p>
</div>
....
<div id="div1">
 <p>text2</p>
</div>
....
<div id="div1">
 <p>text3</p>
</div>
....
```

I've used this but it only change font size of first div:

```
   $('#div1 > p')
   .each(function()
   { 

     $(this).attr('style', 'font-size: 7px !important');
   
   });
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID. ID must be unique. Use class

Comment: Will this work for you `$('div > p').attr('style', 'font-size: 7px !important');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment you can't have multiple elements with the same `id`, and `id` must be unique. use `class="div1"` and then changes your jquery from `$('#div1 > p')` to `$('.div1 > p')`

Look at it this way:

- `id` = your social security number.
- `class` = information like "Man", "Worker" or other information's that multiple elements can have in common and share.

As Kiranvj and David mention, you can simple use `$('.div1 > p').css('font-size', '7px')`

**Demo**

```js
$('.div1 > p')
  .each(function() {

    $(this).attr('style', 'font-size: 7px !important');

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <p>text1</p>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <p>text2</p>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <p>text3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! I almost forgot that. this is the right answer.

Comment: `$('.div1 > p').attr('style', 'font-size: 7px !important');` should work right? Do we need an `each` here?

Comment: @kiranvj No you are right, but the reason why I left it, is incase OP is using something more, but your example would also work.

Comment: `.css('font-size', '7px')` would be my suggestion, rather than using `attr()`>

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Yes there is many ways to improve the current code, but I've focused on explaining the problem with the OP code.